# uwp xaml - Set custom input format to textbox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

is ti possible to (simply) get a specific format on textboxes? Like this

[image: result]

So I have xaml code like this:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" PlaceholderText="100" Height="52" Width="80" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="25" />
```

But I want to have a format on it. So it cant get filled with wrong data.

So one input field has to be `int`s only, another one has to be format `00:00` So 0 is an int from 0-9 and then it auto has to add the `:` and allow two more ints.

Is that possible and how?

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892901/windows-10-universal-windows-app-data-validation tells you to use prism, this here is lengthy but might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43268648/mvvm-validation-in-uwp

Comment: It's not as validaton, but as a sort of regex preset (so if I start typing, it automatically fills in stuff), Like you would have with javascript ( https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/PzpoWK )

Comment: You could potentially write a behaviour for this sort of thing, though the exact output of what you need I'm not sure what it would look like. Here's an example of a numeric textbox [behaviour](http://julmar.com/blog/programming/numerictextboxbehavior-wsa/). Maybe it will give some inspiration to you.

Comment: Check out the UWP Community Toolkit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/extensions/textboxregex

Comment: Another option is to add the ':' automatically when the user writes the second number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was waiting for good question in SO about UWP, and I have Something which might useful --

**XAML**

```
<TextBox Name="MyTextBox" PlaceholderText="00:00" Height="52" Width="80" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="25" MaxLength="5" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
```

**C#**

```
bool m_BackPressed = false; // It is because if user pres back button then it will remove ":" sign else it will never removed

private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    m_BackPressed = (e.Key.ToString().Equals("Back")) ? true : false;

    if (e.Key.ToString().Equals("Back"))
    {
        e.Handled = false;
        return;
        m_BackPressed = true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (e.Key.ToString() == string.Format("Number{0}", i) || e.Key.ToString() == string.Format("NumberPad{0}", i))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
            return;
        }
    }            
    e.Handled = true;
}        

private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyTextBox.Text.Length == 2 && m_BackPressed != true)
    {
        MyTextBox.Text += ":";
        MyTextBox.Select(MyTextBox.Text.Length, 0);                
    }            
}
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: awesome! exactly what I need!

Comment: Is it also possible to 'limit' the amount of numbers? (like let's say `xx:xx` so that is the max amount of chars you can insert?

Comment: @Robin looks like you are not copied my xaml code i already limit the number of characters to 5 inc. that : Symbol 

Comment: @Robin are you get that MaxLength property in xaml ?